# Why does my Node app return 404 on this POST request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm so sure that I made some silly error somewhere in my app, but I just can't seem to find it.

So here's what my Express app looks like. I have my routes set up as such:

```
var routes = require('./routes');
...
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/embed', routes.embed);
app.post('/upload', routes.upload);
```

In my routes folder, I have two files. The index.js file exports the two request handlers `.index` and `.embed`. It might be helpful to know that `.embed` creates a CSRF token to be used on the `/embed` page:

```
exports.embed = function(req, res){
  var csrf = req.session._csrf;
  res.render('embed', { token: csrf });
};


form#secret-form(name="secret-form", method="post", action="/upload", style="")
  input(type="hidden", name="_csrf", value="#{token}")
  input(type="hidden", name="image")
  input#send-button(type="submit") Upload
```

Just a brief note if it's causing the issue: I did attach a `.submit` jQuery handler to this form; it simply grabs the data URL from a canvas object on this page, and puts that as the value to the input field with the name "image".

The `.upload` route is handled in the routes/upload.js file. It looks something like this:

```
exports.upload = function(req, res) {
  console.log("Receiving upload...");
  var imageURL = req.body.image;
  // snippet of code that grabs a canvas data URL and stores it in a file
};
```

I don't think the contents of this function matters because I get the following log output for requests going to `/upload` from the `/embed` form. It doesn't even print the "Receiving upload..." line; it simply returns a page that says "Cannot POST /upload":

```
127.0.0.1 - - [Thu, 26 Jul 2012 04:07:41 GMT] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 404 - "http://0.0.0.0:3000/embed"
```

So, what can I possibly be doing wrong here? Is it my app configuration? I suspect it might be so since the POST requests stopped working after I added CSRF support. But now I'm just speculating...

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  //app.use(express.limit('1mb'));
  app.use(express.query());
  app.use(express.logger());

  // CSRF stuff
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: "secret", cookie: { maxAge: 60000 } }));
  app.use(express.csrf());

  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

Comment: Does your `routes/index.js` file pull in `routes/upload.js` with a `require`?

Comment: Now it does (added `var upload = require("./upload.js")` at the top of the file), but it doesn't help. I assumed that if it wasn't being included properly, I would get an exception along the lines of `routes.upload` being undefined.

Comment: You also need to add `upload` to the `exports` of `index.js`.

Comment: Wow, it worked! I added `exports.upload = upload.upload` (since `upload` is really a function in that module). Thanks! You should add that as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `index.js` file should look something like this so that `routes.upload` actually refers to the `upload` export of `upload.js`:

```
exports.upload = require('./upload').upload;

exports.index = function(...

exports.embed = function(...
```

Comment: I felt that a follow up was necessary in case any other Node beginners stumble upon this: to my surprise, it turns out that if the request handler is `null` or even `undefined`, Express does not actually throw an error. In addition, it also turns out that `require('./routes')` does not actually include an entire directory.